# How to define values in KeyPairValue in java

Tags: java

I do have lot of roles for my app.

```
private static HashMap<String, String> doctorcredentials = new HashMap<String, String>("doctor","Test1234!");
```

It throws me error to remove the arguments. Everytime do i need this credentials by adding only. Can not define directly?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from compiling your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap()) there is no constructor that can create [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) from collection other than existing Map

```
    public HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)
```

The proper way to fulfill the new HashMap is adding pairs one by one after creating new instance

```
    private static HashMap<String, String> doctorcredentials = new HashMap<String, String>();
    doctorcredentials.put("doctor","Test1234!");
    //etc...
```

---

Anyway you can create a Factory class that will be creating HashMaps for you - something like

```
    //You need to add casting exception handling, no argument situation etc...
    public class HashMapFactory<T, V> { 
        public HashMap<T, V> create(Object... arg) {
            HashMap<T, V> map = new HashMap<T, V>();

            for(int i = 1; i < arg.length; i+=2) {
                map.put((T)arg[i-1], (V)arg[i]);
            }

            return map;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use this like

```
    HashMapFactory<String, String> factory = new HashMapFactory<String, String>();

    HashMap<String, String> map = factory.create("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
    System.out.println(map.get("five"));
```

Answer (score 3):

HashMap does not have a constructor to support the arguments you specified. Please refer [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

To put values in hashmap use as specified under

```
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

hm.put("first", "FIRST INSERTED"); 
hm.put("second", "SECOND INSERTED"); 
hm.put("third","THIRD INSERTED");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply declare your map like this:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> doctorcredentials = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("doctor","Test1234!");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
private static HashMap<String, String> doctorcredentials = new HashMap<String, String>();
doctorcredentials.put("doctor","Test1234!");
```